The integral of von Mises distribution and modified Bessel function]
I've been investigating the expected projection length of a random vector on a hemisphere, given than the random vector is distributed according to a $3\mbox{D}$ von-Mises-Fisher Distribution:

After some simplification, I ended up having to calculate the integral of the following:
\begin{align}
& \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \exp\left(\rule{0pt}{5mm}\,\kappa\mu_{z}\cos\left(\theta\right)
\cos\left(\theta\right)\sin\left(\theta\right)
\,\right)
\\ & \int_{0}^{2\pi} \exp\left(\rule{0pt}{6mm}\,\kappa\left[\rule{0pt}{5mm}\,\mu_{x}\cos\left(\phi\right)\sin\left(\theta\right) + \mu_{y}\sin\left(\phi\right) \sin\left(\theta\right)\,\right]\,\right)\,
{\rm d}\phi\,{\rm d}\theta
\end{align}
$(\mu_x, \mu_y, \mu_z)$ (unit vector) and $\kappa$ is the parameter of the vMF distribution. If we integrate $\phi$ out first, we will have after further simplification:
$$
2\pi\int_{0}^{\pi/2} 
\left(\exp(\kappa\mu_z\cos\theta)\cos\theta\sin\theta\right) \times  I_0(\sin\theta \sqrt{a^2 + b^2})  d\theta
$$
where $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = \kappa \sqrt{1 - \mu_z^2}$, is a constant. $I_0$ is the 0-order modified Bessel function of the first kind. Now this bothers me a lot, since though $\sin\theta d\theta$ can be clearly converted to $-d\cos\theta$ and we have:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} 
x\exp(\alpha x) I_0(\beta\sqrt{1 - x^2})  dx
$$
The above integral can not be approximated (or can it?) by expanding $I_0$ into a power series and drop high order terms, since $\beta = \kappa \sqrt{1 - \mu_z^2}$ could be extremely large (when the vMF is relatively concentrated thus $\kappa$ is large). Therefore I am wonder if there is any solution (or approximation) to this integral. Any suggestion would help.

